# Multilevel Model - 2 Levels

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, multilevel-analysis

I got my data from a questionanire, where I had group1 30 individuals vs group2 30 individuals. They answered on 6 questions (from those 6 questions, I got weights on advice (my DV) that range from 0 to 1 (continuous data)). To analyze it, I though it would be good idea to do a multilevel model. So then level 1 is individuals, level 2 - group 1 and 2. But when I did a multilevel model (GLM) with level 2 - group (2 groups), the icc equals 0. Does it mean that I cannot use a multilevel model or am I doing smth wrong? 
 If I cannot, on which regression should I focus then?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! will do it!